# Fibonacci numbers - Out of global stack error

Tags: prolog, out-of-memory, infinite-loop

Consider this simple Prolog program:

```
nat(0).
nat(s(X)) :- nat(X).
plus(X, 0, X) :- nat(X).
plus(X, s(Y), s(Z)) :- nat(X), nat(Y), nat(Z), plus(X, Y, Z).
fib(0, 0).
fib(s(0), s(0)).
fib(s(s(K)), Z) :- fib(s(K), Y), fib(K, X), plus(X, Y, Z).
```

I already tested `plus` and it seems to be working. Let's see if `fib` works okay as well...

```
?- fib(0, 0).
true.

?- fib(s(0), s(0)).
true ;
false.

?- fib(s(s(0)), s(0)).
true ;
false.

?- fib(s(s(s(0))), s(s(0))).
true ;
ERROR: Out of global stack
```

Everything works splendidly until I want to print out the 3rd number, which happens to be 2!

I understand that simulating the Peano arithmetic this way is far from effective, and also that an exponential algorithm that is being used here is suboptimal, nonetheless I refuse to believe that performance issues kick in that early, when I'm only computing the third number. Therefore my program surely loops and therefore it is wrong.

... why does it loop? and what does it take to make it stop looping?

Comment: Did you use `trace`.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Short answer**: It loops because **`plus(0, s(0), X).`** will produce `true`, and then loop.

If we take a look at the `trace`, we see:

```
[trace]  ?- fib(s(s(s(0))), s(s(0))).
   Call: (8) fib(s(s(s(0))), s(s(0))) ? creep
   Call: (9) fib(s(s(0)), _902) ? creep
   Call: (10) fib(s(0), _906) ? creep
   Exit: (10) fib(s(0), s(0)) ? creep
   Call: (10) fib(0, _910) ? creep
   Exit: (10) fib(0, 0) ? creep
   Call: (10) plus(0, s(0), _912) ? creep
   ...
   Exit: (9) plus(s(0), s(0), s(s(0))) ? creep
   Exit: (8) fib(s(s(s(0))), s(s(0))) ? creep
true .
```

But the interpreter backtracks in that predicate and aims to find more solutions. This is due to the fact that your `nat(Z)` each time comes up with a next value, and then the interpreter calls `plus(X, Y, Z)` to check if that matches, but each time it fails.

We can see that when we trace `plus(0, s(0), X)`:

```
[trace]  ?- plus(0, s(0), X).
   Call: (8) plus(0, s(0), _676) ? creep
   Call: (9) nat(0) ? creep
   Exit: (9) nat(0) ? creep
   Call: (9) nat(0) ? creep
   Exit: (9) nat(0) ? creep
   Call: (9) nat(_884) ? creep
   Exit: (9) nat(0) ? creep
   Call: (9) plus(0, 0, 0) ? creep
   Call: (10) nat(0) ? creep
   Exit: (10) nat(0) ? creep
   Exit: (9) plus(0, 0, 0) ? creep
   Exit: (8) plus(0, s(0), s(0)) ? creep
X = s(0) ;
   Redo: (9) plus(0, 0, 0) ? creep
   Fail: (9) plus(0, 0, 0) ? creep
   Redo: (9) nat(_884) ? creep
   Call: (10) nat(_888) ? creep
   Exit: (10) nat(0) ? creep
   Exit: (9) nat(s(0)) ? creep
   Call: (9) plus(0, 0, s(0)) ? creep
   Fail: (9) plus(0, 0, s(0)) ? creep
   Redo: (10) nat(_888) ? creep
```

Of course none of the answers `nat(Z)` will propose will succeed once `plus(0, s(0), X)` has succeeded.

There is however no reason to call `nat(Z)` anyway, since eventually the recursive call will land in the basecase that will validate `nat(X)`, so we can implement it like:

```
plus(X, 0, X) :- nat(X).
plus(X, s(Y), s(Z)) :- plus(X, Y, Z).
```

It is also typically more efficient to use different patterns on the *first* parameter:

```
plus(0, X, X) :- nat(X).
plus(s(X), Y, s(Z)) :- plus(X, Y, Z).
```